# Vue.js: No image displayed when binding data URI to src attribute of img element

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

**SOLVED**: Not surprisingly, the error was mine, not Vue's. I had set `opacity: 0` to all `img` elements with a `data-src` attribute (for lazy loading), so the images were there, they just weren't visible because of the opacity setting.

---

I'm passing a data URI as a prop to a Vue component and binding it to the `src` attribute of an `img` element, but the image does not appear. Here's the relevant code:

Passing the prop to the component (ignore the `image_ratio` key name, it's a data URI):

```
<media-image
  v-if="event.media_type === 'image'"
  :url="event.media_url"
  :caption="event.media_caption"
  :imageUri="event.image_ratio"></media-image>
```

Accepting the prop within the component:

```
props: [
    'url',
    'caption',
    'imageUri'
],
```

And using binding the src to the prop:

```
<img :src="imageUri" :data-src="url" class="img-fluid" :id="imageId" :alt="caption">
```

Other relevant info:

- The prop is successfully being passed to the component (it appears as a prop using vue-devtools).
- The data URI appears in the DOM as the src of the img element when inspecting it using DevTools.
- Copying the data URI and using it as the src of an img element outside of a Vue component works fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you define `imageId` anywhere?

Comment: How is the template specified for `media-image`?

Comment: Yes, it's a computed property.

Comment: The template is HTML markup surrounded by `<template>` tags in a single file component.

Comment: What is the version of Vue.js are you using? How about trying these two: `v-bind:src="imageUri"` and `:src="{{imageUri}}"`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I gave them both a shot but neither worked. I'm using version 2.4.2.